# How can I use MS Access to Link to a Read-Only SQL table to add attachments

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to create a MS Access database that links an SQL table (read only) to another table that only holds attachments. The SQL table holds information about various non-profit companies in our area, and the Access table would hold PDF flyers, MS Word, etc., in an attachment field.

In my mind, that should be a one-to-one relationship and I should be able to create a form importing the SQL fields and including the attachments from the Access table. I have no problem linking Access to the SQL table and importing all the data, but I can't figure out how to link to the attachments. I am not allowed to change the SQL table, so I can't add a field there. No matter how I try to link the relationship, I either get a blank form with no data, or a type mismatch error.

Suggestions?

Comment: In my mind, if the non-profit could possibly have more than one attachment, would that instead be one-to-many? Anyway, can you show the structure that you have for the to tables?

Comment: Attachment field is a multi-value type. Multiple objects can be in the same field for one record - although they are really stored in a hidden table. What are the key fields you are joining the two tables on and what are the data types?

Comment: I would advise against using the attachment field. It'll bloat the db, it's error prone and easily corrupts, it's better to store the file path to the file and then use that to interact